# Use variable inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to find a way to insert my variable(s) into ng-repeat,
see examples below for explanation.

*controller.js*

```
$scope.firstParams = $stateParams.firstId;
```

*template.html*

```
<span style="margin-left:3px;" ng-repeat="list in user.userlists.{{firstParams}}"></span>
```

**ng-repeat example is just for displaying purpose**

Basically what I want to do is having my ng-repeat fetch the params via ***$scope.firstParams*** and have it like so: *ng-repeat="list in user.userlists.gameboy"* if the params would be "gameboy".

I tried a bunch of  *filter:Options* with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript you use `[]` notation for variable property names

Try

```
ng-repeat="list in user.userlists[firstParams]"
```

Demo Link - http://jsfiddle.net/tk11wz7j/

Comment: Thanks!! This is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

the {{value}} is for rendering a value, what you need is a filter for example

`list in user.userlists | filter: firstParams`

Comment: Thanks for explaining the rendering part, it makes sense now :)
charlietfl's answer was what i was looking for